# Use and re-use some objects (Subclass of UIView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I wonder, from a memory point of view, if what I'm doing is correct.
First, the files that I want to re-use are subclasses of `UIViews`.
In my `UIViewcontroller`, I declare an object like this :

**World_1_ViewController.h :**

```
#import "Level1.h"

@class Level1;

@interface World_1_ViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
{
    Some things....
    Level1 * level1view;
}
```

**World_1_ViewController.m :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:level1view];

    //Other things...
}
```

You could see that it's init a first time when the `UIViewController` `World_1_ViewController` is opening, in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Now i need to re-use this object, `level1view`, so in one of my methods which come after, I use:

```
[level1view release];
level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];
//Some methods...
```

Is it correct from a memory point of view? Or what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[level1view release];
level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];
Some methods...
```

in that code you should also remove your current view from superView, like that

```
[level1view removeFromSuperview];
[level1view release];
level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];
Some methods...
```

also you should release level1view in `dealloc` and `didReciveMemoryWarning` methods,
and set it to `nil`

**updated:**

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [level1view release];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReciveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReciveMemoryWarning];
    if (!self.isViewLoaded) {
        [level1view release];
         level1view = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I put [level1view release]; in the dealloc method of my World_1_ViewController, but what would i add in the didReciveMemoryWarning method (and even in general ?) ? What would i set to nil ?

Comment: So i should put all my objects like this : [level1view release];
         level1view = nil; after if (!self.isViewLoaded) ?

Comment: not all objects, only some views, read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430728/how-to-implement-didreceivememorywarning and that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921360/iphone-memory-management-didreceivememorywarning

Comment: Looks not working when i add [level1view removeFromSuperview]; :(

Comment: Do you release level1view in viewdidLoad?

Comment: Nop, think i found another solution =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no parameter changes and just want to have same view more then once then just alloc only once like shown below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if(level1view==nil)
         level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:level1view];

    Other things...
}
```

Comment: So you're agree with the other answer ? =)

Comment: Do you want to have level1view exactly once (mean one level1view in xib) or multiple instance of level1view(more than one view in xib) ?

Comment: I don't use xib, but one level1view, and re-use it after but when the first is not use for sure

Comment: I guess you don't need to release and alloc again as once you allocated you can reuse that object. But [self.view addSubview:level1view]; will keep adding instance of level1view so make sure to use [level1view removeFromSuperview]; in this case.

Comment: @Bhargavi A view can have only one superview, so calling addSubview with it multiple times will not add multiple instances to the view.

Comment: @James a view can have only one superview but superview can have multiple view. :).Using [self.view addSubview:level1view]; at random places in your code more than once means level1view will get added in self.view that many times. Its so simple and logical.

Comment: @Bhargavi No it won't, try it. A view can have multiple subviews, but those subviews have to be different instances.

Answer (score 0):

use singleton method for creating instance for handling memory use like this

```
   static Level1 *_sharedMySingleton;

  @implementation Level1

  +(Level1 *) getLevel1Instance
    {
        @synchronized([Level1 class])
        {
            if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            {
                _sharedMySingleton = [[self alloc] init];

            }
            return _sharedMySingleton;
        }
        return nil;
    }
@end
```

While creating instance replace this

```
level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];
```

with

```
 level1view = [level1view removeFromSuperview];
level1view = [Level1 getLevel1Instance];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];
```

Try like this.

Comment: And what should be _sharedMySingleton ?

Comment: Thank you =) And so when i re-use level1view, i don't have to put : level1view = [level1view removeFromSuperview]; or [level1view release]; ?

Comment: [level1view release]; no need to use, but  level1view = [level1view removeFromSuperview]; you needs to use as per your purpose.

Comment: And need to something in the didReciveMemoryWarning method ?

Comment: @user2057209 - No need to handle any thing there.

Comment: No when i realloc the new element level1view = [Level1 getLevel1Instance];
[self.view addSubview:level1view];, it didn't print anything :/

Comment: It gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Updated the answer. r u using like this or not before reallocating?

Comment: Yes i was using like this, and this goes to a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error :/

Comment: May i know the reason for -1?

Comment: I think a singleton for a view is a bad idea. I doubt you want this hanging around in memory for the lifetime of your app. And it looks like the OP wants to create a new instance of this view anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to declare about property like this.

```
@interface World_1_ViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
{
    Some things....
    Level1 * level1view;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) Level1 * level1view;
```

and also use "self." or "_" to access variable via setter or getter.

If you wanna check that object is released or not, you can check "retainCount" to use "- (NSUInteger)retainCount" like this.

```
printf("%d\n", [_level1view retainCount]);
```

When retainCount is 0, that object must be released.

Comment: You shouldn't use retainCount: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount

Comment: `retainCount` can never return 0.